# xcode iOS Simulator will dim part of the display down, then back to normal over and over again

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Has anyone experienced this behavior?  Is there anything I can do about it?

When running any of my apps in the iOS simulator, my screen (external monitor) will show a patch of dimmer colors. Usually the whole simulator, but sometimes the line cuts right through it.

This happened in all versions of xcode from 4 to the latest GM of xcode 5.

It's frustrating because I like to record the screen to show demos of my apps, but the constant dimming / un-dimming makes it look bad.

Comment: Does this happen only for your app or even if you just use the simulated apps (like Safari or the Settings app)?

Comment: Good point. I just tried watching a video on youtube and found that the same thing is happening. If I move the simulator by clicking near the top and dragging it, the shading clears up... but comes back again shortly afterwards.  Sometimes it's the entire view, other times there's a distinct starting edge of the shaded area near the left of the view.